# Need delay between two Flutter transitions in AnimatedSwitcher

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-web

I need a short delay between two transitions in the AnimatedSwitcher transitionBuilder. I tried Future.delayed, but it doesn't return a widget. What should I use?

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                          transitionBuilder: (
                            Widget child,
                            Animation<double> animation,
                          ) {
                            return SlideTransition(
                              position: Tween<Offset>(
                                      begin: Offset(0.0, 0.1),
                                      end: Offset(0, 0))
                                  .animate(animation),
                              child: FadeTransition(
                                opacity: animation,
                                child: child,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: quizStep(quiz, screenWidth),
                        ),
```

The FadeTransition must execute a few seconds after the SlideTransition.

Comment: Did you use [Interval class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Interval-class.html#:~:text=An%20Interval%20can%20be%20used,that%20starts%20three%20seconds%20later.)

Comment: I tried using Interval class, but failed to implement in the above code..  could you please help?

Comment: Sure, can you share the full code?

Comment: Sorry, Mohammed explained Interval class using only the code given. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case as you are using the animation for fade and scale, the animation will start and stop in the same time.
However you can use staggered animation, you will find more about it here:https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations

the solution is

```
              FadeTransition(
                opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
                  CurvedAnimation(
                    parent: animation,
                    curve: Interval(0.5, 1.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: child,
              ),
```

Interval curve is to tell when the animation start and when it ends.
the value should be between 0.0 and 1.0 as it's the animation value, 0.5 will start the animation after the half time of the animation time(half second), you should tweak it and find the best value that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks... But this gives a delay between switching two widgets. I need a delay between the two transitions FadeTransition and SlideTransition..

Comment: sorry i didn't got your question first
I will edit the answer